# Email Verification with DNS & SMTP Check from Heroku Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, heroku, dns

I'm thinking to use this gem https://github.com/kamilc/email_verifier to verify email addresses.

Basically this gem will check for MX record in DNS and connects with the smtp to check if an email address really exists or not. Does anyone have experience with this type of things please advice my concerns.

Does querying too many times to dns and smtp from my app, hurt my domain reputation?

I know that heroku switch ip addreses for all dynos everyday, is this same case for my ssl app as well?

Comment: I think it depends on your needs. If you just need to know if an email exists, this gem may work (I have never used it). If you need to know if the user actually has access to the email address, then you should send them an email with a link and/or access token that can be entered into your site.

Comment: Thank you I can see this gem working perfectly for me now, I'm just worried what if some server report my ip/domain as spam.

Comment: IMHO I wouldn't do this. MX records don't have to exist. Mail servers don't have to tell you if an address is legitimate or not unless you actually send an email (and sometimes not even then) and yes, some will start tracking your connection attempts and block you. Think of it this way, if the above worked reliably wouldn't every spammer in the world use it to find everyone's email address?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, I have experience (from a few years ago) of doing pretty much exactly that at a large scale. We were scanning the entire .SE domain ("we" in this case being the .SE registry), and tried to verify the addresses in the SOA records.

I strongly advice you not to bother with the SMTP part. The false-positive *and* false-negative rates will be plenty high enough to make your results meaningless, and your server will quickly get blacklisted by all major mail service providers.

Checking the DNS part makes sense and works well. Use a library with a good reputation to check the syntax of the email address (do *not* try to write it yourself, it's way more complex than you think), and if it passes check that the domain looks deliverable. "Looks deliverable" means that it either has MX records that can be resolved to IP addresses, or if it does not have any MX records, that it has A and/or AAAA record(s).

Don't try to contact the IP addresses you find. It takes a lot of time (relatively speaking), and it tells you nothing. If you can connect, start an SMTP transaction and the other end says "Sure, I can deliver that" you *still* don't know if the address you're testing is good, since most mail servers these days will say they accept everything and then silently drop invalid messages on the floor. They do this precisely to prevent spammers from doing exactly what you're trying to do (verifying addresses), so don't expect that behavior to change until the spammers go away. If the server says "Nope, can't deliver that now, try again later", it may be using greylisting. So you could maybe get a good answer -- if you try again in five or ten minutes. You probably don't want your Ruby method call to take ten minutes. And finally, if the server says "Nope, can't deliver that, ever", you still can't know if that means the address is invalid of if the server is having a bad day, and the address may start working at some point in the future.

So to sum up, if you try to do SMTP connections to validate mail addresses, you will spend a lot of time (both when writing the code and when running it), you'll piss off a lot of people, get put on a lot of blacklists (some of which are very, very much more eager to add things than to take them off again) and at the end of it all you *still* won't know any more than you did before you started. It's really not worth it.

Comment: Thank you so much for such an elaborate answer, I decided to skip this verification.